# Newbie: Can't connect to database using browser

Tags: browser, neo4j

Recently installed Neo4J on a Raspberry Pi on a docker container (portainer). Everything seems to working fine. I can open a terminal in Portainer and run commands. I can see there are two DB and I can even run Cypher commands (cut and pasted the Movie entries). But I'm not able to run any commands using the browser. I seem to be able to connect the browser (http://localhost:7474/browser/) and see the ":play movie-graph" run. But when I try to run the query to enter movie data, I get the following error: "ERROR: Neo.DatabaseError.General.UnknownError" Running :sysinfo doesn't return any results. Also the cursor is $ as opposed to a DB name. And don't see any databases in the Database menu on the left.

Again, I'm able to run queries using Cypher Shell through a Portainer terminal.

Here are the container details:

```
IMAGE   neo4j:latest@sha256:b91a4a85afb0cec9892522436bbbcb20f1d6d026c8c24cafcbcc4e27b5c8b68d
CMD neo4j
ENTRYPOINT  tini -g -- /startup/docker-entrypoint.sh
ENV 
JAVA_HOME   /usr/local/openjdk-11
JAVA_VERSION    11.0.15
LANG    C.UTF-8
NEO4J_AUTH  none
NEO4J_dbms_connector_bolt_advertised__address   localhost:7687
NEO4J_dbms_connector_http_advertised__address   localhost:7474
NEO4J_dbms_connector_https_advertised__address  localhost:7473
NEO4J_EDITION   community
NEO4J_HOME  /var/lib/neo4j
NEO4J_SHA256    34c8ce7edc2ab9f63a204f74f37621cac3427f12b0aef4c6ef47eaf4c2b90d66
NEO4J_TARBALL   neo4j-community-4.4.8-unix.tar.gz
PATH    /var/lib/neo4j/bin:/usr/local/openjdk-11/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

[image]
[image]
I'm sure it is something silly I'm missing, but reading multiple forum comments haven't help. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

SJ

Answer (score 0):

When you load the neo4jbrowser from your internet browser at:

```
http://localhost:7474/browser
```

, you need to connect to the bolt advertised address of your neo4j server at:

```
bolt://localhost:7687
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. That is how I'm connecting. It shows I'm connected, but not able to run any queries. Please see attached.

Comment: check your debug.log and add the exact error message that appear in the log when you try to enter a simple query  like for example MATCH (n) RETURN count(n);